# How to bind a command inside style in WP8?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, binding

I need to bind a command inside the  style of a button, I tried using following code but it's not working

```
     <Style x:Key="Button_ML" TargetType="Button">  
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> 
     <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},ElementName=grdSearch}"/>      
      <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">  
  </Style>
```

ViewModel:

```
        private RelayCommand<string> _buttonClickCommand;
        public RelayCommand<string> ButtonClickCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return this._buttonClickCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((value) => this.ClickButton(value));
            }
        }

        private void ClickButton(string text)
        {
            if (text.Equals("Space"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                this.Text += text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you share your ViewModel ?

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil: Edited the question.

Comment: from your code your xaml code,this command exists in the dataContext of a UI element "grdSearch" ? right ?

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil:Yes

Comment: What about changing your public property ButtonClickCommand type to ICommand ??

Comment: @Med.Amine:Still no change

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil `RelayCommand` is inherited by `ICommand` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand(v=vs.110).aspx

@JustinCI Do you have any binding error in output window ?

Comment: @Eldho:No I dont have any error in output window

Comment: `<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                        <mvvmlight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator},
                                                                                    Path=MyViewModel.MyCommand}"
                                                                 />
                                    </interactivity:EventTrigger>` This works in wpf